# Rails 3 Validation on Stored attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, validation, activerecord

Well, we all know the new amazing feature of last [ActiveRecord::Store](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Store.html) class.

But how can we do validations safely? Here an example:

```
class User
  has_many :posts
end

class Post
  belongs_to :user
  store :composed_attribute, accessors: [:attribute_1, :attribute_2]

  validates :attribute_1, presence: true # This works great!
  validates :attribute_2, presence: true,  uniqueness: {scope: :user_id, message: "must be unique."} # This fails!
end
```

The first validation works great, but the second fails with and *undestandable* `undefined method 'text?' for nil:NilClass`.

In database everything is stored in yaml format. but we cannot be sure about the order, so which is the best way to perform such validation?

**Disclaimer**

I know that, maybe, in this case store the attributes together is not a great idea, mostly for performance issues, but it's an interesting topic anyway.